# How to access AWS CloudFront that connected with S3 Bucket via Bearer token of a specific user (JWT Custom Auth)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, oauth-2.0, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudfront

I am using a serverless framework to deploy a serverless stack to AWS. My stack consists of some lambda functions, DynamoDB tables and API Gateway.

I am protected The API Gateway using what's called [lambda authorizer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/configure-api-gateway-lambda-authorization-with-console.html). Also, I have a custom standalone self-hosted Auth service that can generate tokens.

So the scenario is that the user can request a token from this service (It's IdentityServer4 hosted on Azure) then the user can send a request to the API Gateway with the bearer token so the API gateway will ask the lambda authorizer to generate iam roles if the token is correct. All of that is valid and works as expected.

Here is an example of the lambda authorizer definition in my serverless.yml and how I use it to protect other API gateway endpoints: (You can see the addUserInfo function has API that protected using the custom authorizer )

```
functions:
    # =================================================================
    # API Gateway event handlers
    # ================================================================
  auth:
    handler: api/auth/mda-auth-server.handler

  addUserInfo:
     handler: api/user/create-replace-user-info.handler
     description: Create Or Replace user section
     events:
       - http:
           path: user
           method: post
           authorizer: 
             name: auth
             resultTtlInSeconds: ${self:custom.resultTtlInSeconds}
             identitySource: method.request.header.Authorization
             type: token
           cors:
             origin: '*'
             headers: ${self:custom.allowedHeaders}
```

Now I wanted to extend my APIs so I will allow the user to add images, so I followed this [approach](https://serverlessfirst.com/serverless-photo-upload-api/). So in this approach, the user will initiate what's called a signed S3 URL and I can put an image to my bucket using this S3 signed URL.

Also, the S3 bucket is not publicly accessible but instead, it's connected to CloudFront distribution. Now I missed the things here, I can't understand how I can protect my images. Is it anyway so I can protect the Images in the CloudFront CDN with my custom Authentication service so the user that has a valid token can just access those resources? How can I protect my CDN (CloudFront) using my Custom Authentication service and configure that using the serverless framework?

Comment: Have you had a look at this AWS documentation? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/PrivateContent.html (It may not solve your problem, but would be good to understand why that doesn't meet your requirements, as it is a supported AWS pattern)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bit tricky and it takes from me around a day to get all set.

First we have options here:

- Instead of authentication we can sign the URL and return a signed CloudFront URL or signed S3 URL and it's pretty straight forward but obviously that not what I was looking for.
- The second option is to use Lambda@Edge to authorize the requests of the CloudFront and that what I followed.

So I ended up create a separate stack to handle all the S3, CloudFront, and Lambda@Edge stuff cause they are all deployed on edges which means that the region doesn't matter but for lambda edge we need to deploy it to the main AWS region ((N. Virginia), us-east-1) So i ended up creating one stack for all of them.

First I have the below code in my auth-service.js (It's just some helpers to allow me to verify my custom jwt):

```
import * as jwtDecode from 'jwt-decode';
import * as util from 'util';
import * as jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';
import * as jwksClient from 'jwks-rsa';


export function getToken(bearerToken) {
    if(bearerToken && bearerToken.startsWith("Bearer "))
    {
        return bearerToken.replace(/^Bearer\s/, '');
    }
    throw new Error("Invalid Bearer Token.");
};

export function getDecodedHeader(token) {
        return jwtDecode(token, { header: true });
};

export async function getSigningKey(decodedJwtTokenHeader, jwksclient){
    const key = await util.promisify(jwksclient.getSigningKey)(decodedJwtTokenHeader.kid);
    const signingKey = key.publicKey || key.rsaPublicKey;
    if (!signingKey) {
        throw new Error('could not get signing key');
    }
    return signingKey;
  };

export async function verifyToken(token,signingKey){
    return await jwt.verify(token, signingKey);
};

export function getJwksClient(jwksEndpoint){
    return jwksClient({
        cache: true,
        rateLimit: true,
        jwksRequestsPerMinute: 10,
        jwksUri: jwksEndpoint
      });
};
```

Then inside the serverless.yml here is my file:

```
service: mda-app-uploads

plugins:
  - serverless-offline
  - serverless-pseudo-parameters
  - serverless-iam-roles-per-function
  - serverless-bundle


custom:
  stage: ${opt:stage, self:provider.stage}
  resourcesBucketName: ${self:custom.stage}-mda-resources-bucket
  resourcesStages:
    prod: prod
    dev: dev
  resourcesStage: ${self:custom.resourcesStages.${self:custom.stage}, self:custom.resourcesStages.dev}


provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs12.x
  stage: ${opt:stage, 'dev'}
  region: us-east-1
  versionFunctions: true

functions: 
  oauthEdge:
    handler: src/mda-edge-auth.handler
    role: LambdaEdgeFunctionRole
    memorySize: 128
    timeout: 5


resources:
  - ${file(resources/s3-cloudfront.yml)}
```

Quick points here:

- The us-east-1 important here.
- It's a bit tricky and not practical to create any lambda edge using the serverless framework so I used it to just configure the function and then inside this cloud formation template `resources/s3-cloudfront.yml` I added all the needed bits.

Then here is the content of `resources/s3-cloudfront.yml`:

```
Resources:

    AuthEdgeLambdaVersion:
        Type: Custom::LatestLambdaVersion
        Properties:
            ServiceToken: !GetAtt PublishLambdaVersion.Arn
            FunctionName: !Ref OauthEdgeLambdaFunction
            Nonce: "Test"

    PublishLambdaVersion:
        Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
        Properties:
            Handler: index.handler
            Runtime: nodejs12.x
            Role: !GetAtt PublishLambdaVersionRole.Arn
            Code:
                ZipFile: |
                    const {Lambda} = require('aws-sdk')
                    const {send, SUCCESS, FAILED} = require('cfn-response')
                    const lambda = new Lambda()
                    exports.handler = (event, context) => {
                        const {RequestType, ResourceProperties: {FunctionName}} = event
                        if (RequestType == 'Delete') return send(event, context, SUCCESS)
                        lambda.publishVersion({FunctionName}, (err, {FunctionArn}) => {
                        err
                            ? send(event, context, FAILED, err)
                            : send(event, context, SUCCESS, {FunctionArn})
                        })
                    }

    PublishLambdaVersionRole:
        Type: AWS::IAM::Role
        Properties:
            AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
                Version: '2012-10-17'
                Statement:
                - Effect: Allow
                  Principal:
                    Service: lambda.amazonaws.com
                  Action: sts:AssumeRole
            ManagedPolicyArns:
            - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole
            Policies:
            - PolicyName: PublishVersion
              PolicyDocument:
                Version: '2012-10-17'
                Statement:
                - Effect: Allow
                  Action: lambda:PublishVersion
                  Resource: '*'

    LambdaEdgeFunctionRole:
        Type: "AWS::IAM::Role"
        Properties:
            Path: "/"
            ManagedPolicyArns:
                - "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole"
            AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
                Version: "2012-10-17"
                Statement:
                -
                    Sid: "AllowLambdaServiceToAssumeRole"
                    Effect: "Allow"
                    Action: 
                        - "sts:AssumeRole"
                    Principal:
                        Service: 
                            - "lambda.amazonaws.com"
                            - "edgelambda.amazonaws.com"
    LambdaEdgeFunctionPolicy:
        Type: "AWS::IAM::Policy"
        Properties:
            PolicyName: MainEdgePolicy
            PolicyDocument:
                Version: "2012-10-17"
                Statement:
                    Effect: "Allow"
                    Action: 
                        - "lambda:GetFunction"
                        - "lambda:GetFunctionConfiguration"
                    Resource: !GetAtt AuthEdgeLambdaVersion.FunctionArn
            Roles:
                - !Ref LambdaEdgeFunctionRole


    ResourcesBucket:
        Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
        Properties:
            BucketName: ${self:custom.resourcesBucketName}
            AccessControl: Private
            CorsConfiguration:
                CorsRules:
                -   AllowedHeaders: ['*']
                    AllowedMethods: ['PUT']
                    AllowedOrigins: ['*']

    ResourcesBucketPolicy:
        Type: AWS::S3::BucketPolicy
        Properties:
            Bucket:
                Ref: ResourcesBucket
            PolicyDocument:
                Statement:
                # Read permission for CloudFront
                -   Action: s3:GetObject
                    Effect: "Allow"
                    Resource: 
                        Fn::Join: 
                            - ""
                            - 
                                - "arn:aws:s3:::"
                                - 
                                    Ref: "ResourcesBucket"
                                - "/*"
                    Principal:
                        CanonicalUser: !GetAtt CloudFrontOriginAccessIdentity.S3CanonicalUserId
                -   Action: s3:PutObject
                    Effect: "Allow"
                    Resource: 
                        Fn::Join: 
                            - ""
                            - 
                                - "arn:aws:s3:::"
                                - 
                                    Ref: "ResourcesBucket"
                                - "/*"
                    Principal:
                        AWS: !GetAtt LambdaEdgeFunctionRole.Arn

                -   Action: s3:GetObject
                    Effect: "Allow"
                    Resource: 
                        Fn::Join: 
                            - ""
                            - 
                                - "arn:aws:s3:::"
                                - 
                                    Ref: "ResourcesBucket"
                                - "/*"
                    Principal:
                        AWS: !GetAtt LambdaEdgeFunctionRole.Arn

    
    CloudFrontOriginAccessIdentity:
        Type: AWS::CloudFront::CloudFrontOriginAccessIdentity
        Properties:
            CloudFrontOriginAccessIdentityConfig:
                Comment:
                    Fn::Join: 
                        - ""
                        -
                            - "Identity for accessing CloudFront from S3 within stack "
                            - 
                                Ref: "AWS::StackName"
                            - ""


    # Cloudfront distro backed by ResourcesBucket
    ResourcesCdnDistribution:
        Type: AWS::CloudFront::Distribution
        Properties:
            DistributionConfig:
                Origins:
                    # S3 origin for private resources
                    -   DomainName: !Sub '${self:custom.resourcesBucketName}.s3.amazonaws.com'
                        Id: S3OriginPrivate
                        S3OriginConfig:
                            OriginAccessIdentity: !Sub 'origin-access-identity/cloudfront/#{CloudFrontOriginAccessIdentity}'
                    # S3 origin for public resources           
                    -   DomainName: !Sub '${self:custom.resourcesBucketName}.s3.amazonaws.com'
                        Id: S3OriginPublic
                        S3OriginConfig:
                            OriginAccessIdentity: !Sub 'origin-access-identity/cloudfront/#{CloudFrontOriginAccessIdentity}'
                Enabled: true
                Comment: CDN for public and provate static content.
                DefaultRootObject: index.html
                HttpVersion: http2
                DefaultCacheBehavior:
                    AllowedMethods:
                        - DELETE
                        - GET
                        - HEAD
                        - OPTIONS
                        - PATCH
                        - POST
                        - PUT
                    Compress: true
                    TargetOriginId: S3OriginPublic
                    ForwardedValues:
                        QueryString: false
                        Headers:
                        - Origin
                        Cookies:
                            Forward: none
                    ViewerProtocolPolicy: redirect-to-https
                CacheBehaviors:
                    - 
                        PathPattern: 'private/*'
                        TargetOriginId: S3OriginPrivate
                        AllowedMethods:
                        - DELETE
                        - GET
                        - HEAD
                        - OPTIONS
                        - PATCH
                        - POST
                        - PUT
                        Compress: true
                        LambdaFunctionAssociations:
                            - 
                                EventType: viewer-request
                                LambdaFunctionARN: !GetAtt AuthEdgeLambdaVersion.FunctionArn
                        ForwardedValues:
                            QueryString: false
                            Headers:
                                - Origin
                            Cookies:
                                Forward: none
                        ViewerProtocolPolicy: redirect-to-https
                    - 
                        PathPattern: 'public/*'
                        TargetOriginId: S3OriginPublic
                        AllowedMethods:
                        - DELETE
                        - GET
                        - HEAD
                        - OPTIONS
                        - PATCH
                        - POST
                        - PUT
                        Compress: true
                        ForwardedValues:
                            QueryString: false
                            Headers:
                                - Origin
                            Cookies:
                                Forward: none
                        ViewerProtocolPolicy: redirect-to-https

                PriceClass: PriceClass_200
```

Some quick points related to this file:

- Here I created the S3 bucket that will contain all my private and public resources.
- This bucket is private and not accessible and you will find a role who just give the CDN and the lambda edge access to it.
- I decided to create a CloudFront (CDN) with two origins public to be pointed to the S3's public folder and private to point it to the S3's private folder and configure the behavior of the CloudFront private origin to use my lambda edge function for the authentication through the viewer-request event type.
- You will find also a code to create the function version and another function called `PublishLambdaVersion` with its role and it helps to give the lambda edge the correct permissions while deploying.

Finally here it the actually code for the lambda edge function used for CDN auth:

```
import {getJwksClient, getToken, getDecodedHeader, getSigningKey, verifyToken} from '../../../../libs/services/auth-service';
import config from '../../../../config';

const response401 = {
    status: '401',
    statusDescription: 'Unauthorized'
};

exports.handler = async (event) => {
    try{
        const cfrequest = event.Records[0].cf.request;
        const headers = cfrequest.headers;
        if(!headers.authorization) {
            console.log("no auth header");
            return response401;
        }
        const jwtValue = getToken(headers.authorization);
        const client = getJwksClient(`https://${config.authDomain}/.well-known/openid-configuration/jwks`);
        const decodedJwtHeader = getDecodedHeader(jwtValue);
        if(decodedJwtHeader)
        {
          const signingKey = await getSigningKey(decodedJwtHeader, client);
          const verifiedToken = await verifyToken(jwtValue, signingKey);
          if(verifiedToken)
          {
            return cfrequest;
          }
      }else{
        throw Error("Unauthorized");
      }

    }catch(err){
      console.log(err);
      return response401;
    }
};
```

In case you are interested, I am using IdentityServer4 and hosted it as a docker image in Azure and using it as a custom authorizer.

So the full scenario now that we have an S3 bucket that totally private. It's only accessible through the CloudFront origins. If the request served through the public origin so no authentication needed but if it's served through the private origin so is I am triggering what's called lambda edge to authenticate it and validate the bearer token.

I was totally new to AWS stack before going deep into all of those but AWS is quite easy so I end up configured everything in a perfect way. Please let me know in case there is something not clear or if there are any questions.