# Lambda@Edge limitation to be deployed to us-east-1 prevents me from deploying S3 bucket to Europe

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cloudfront, serverless-framework, aws-lambda-edge

Update:

The short version of the issue that I wanted to cross-reference some values in different stacks in different regions but the documentations were so confusing to let me think it's not possible to do that but it's possible, just I had to output those values as exported values in that stack and then use:
`${cf.us-east-1:another-stack.theNeededArn}` in the other stack.

---

The Long version if you are interested:

I am maintaining the infrastructure code using a Serverless framework. I have CloudFront that connecting to an S3 bucket that hosted in Europe. I got a client request to limit access to this bucket through the CloudFront to be limited only to the authenticated users (custom auth). Lambda@Edge was the best solution and I already implemented it that way but because Lambda@Edge has to be deployed to  us-east-1, I ended up moving the S3 and the Cloudfront to the same region us-east-1 (That's because Cloufront depends on the lambda edge and S3 depends on the CloudFront so I have to keep them in the same stack or at least the same region). But I don't want to move my bucket to the US for legal stuff and I want to keep the data in Europe, Also my S3 has a lambda trigger function that listens to it and writes some data to a DynamoDb hosted in Europe.

So The problem:
I had S3 in Europe and I want to keep it in Europe but due to using lambda edge and because that the cloud formation or the serverless doesn't support a cross-region stack reference I ended up moving this S3 to the US but that's not the requirements!

- I think even though we use the cloud front but having all of our customers in Europe and putting the S3 bucket in the US will increase the latency.
- For legal stuff, I want to keep the European user's data inside Europe and not move it outside.

Here in this question's answer, I specified my approach and the full code example in case you are interested: [How to access AWS CloudFront that connected with S3 Bucket via Bearer token of a specific user (JWT Custom Auth)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62492604/how-to-access-aws-cloudfront-that-connected-with-s3-bucket-via-bearer-token-of-a)

Any Suggestions?

---

Update (Steps to show the exact problem):

1. In my serverless.yml, I created this stack contains this lambda
   edge:

[image: Serverless.yml]

I didn't want to configure lambda edge using a serverless framework but instead, I used cloud formation to configure the cloud front and everything.

2. In the cloud formation resources file, I added the cloud front
   origins and configure the private origin through its behavior to use
   the lambda edge (Please check the highlights in the picture):

[image: Cloudfront configs]
Please note that now I am using the lambda edge ARN inside my Cloudfront so they need to be in the same region and because lambda@edge should be in us-east-1 so I decided to move the CloudFront to the same region and that does not really matter cause it has edge behavior by design.

3. Als if you are interested here I defined all the needed roles for
   the predefined lambda edge in the step.1 (And that includes
   publishing the correct policies and also the lambda edge version as
   in lambda edge, you have to reference the version, not the function
   and all set in this step I just put it here for completeness.):

[image: Lambda Edge Configs]

4. Now I have the cloud front configuration, lambda edge configuration,
   and in the cloud front, we are referencing the lambda edge ARN which
   leads me to put them in the same region but now I will define my S3
   bucket and will make it private so no one can access it, just the
   cloud front CloudFrontOriginAccessIdentity can do that:

[image: The Bucket configs]

As you may see in the role I just gave access to CloudFront to get and gave access to the (lambda edge to get and put but not sure if that's correct) but anyways even if we need the CloudFrontOriginAccessIdentity only to be connected to my bucket so now the bucket linked with my CloudFront which is also linked to the lambda edge so I can't separate them to put the S3 in Europe only??

And by that even if I have an S3 trigger lambda function so I should put this function in the US even if this function is doing some stuff related to DynamoDb in Europe? So what is the point? Also even if the Cloudfront is edged but the bucket is regional so if I really need to process some data related to it that means by putting it in us I increased the latency? So that's my full detailed problem.

---

Update2:
I wanted to post the code as screenshots so I can highlight some lines and make it easier but for whom interested to check the code itself, I already posted the full version of it in my answer to this question here: [How to access AWS CloudFront that connected with S3 Bucket via Bearer token of a specific user (JWT Custom Auth)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62492604/how-to-access-aws-cloudfront-that-connected-with-s3-bucket-via-bearer-token-of-a)

Comment: You actually create Lambda@edge function in us-east-1 but it gets deployed in all the regions and the function triggers based on edge the client is connected to, however this doesn’t mandate you to use bucket in us-east-1 , you can use lambda function and still trigger your bucket of europe. You can specify origin as s3 eu endpoint in your lambda@edge function.

Comment: There are dependencies. So basically in the CloudFront configurations, I am specifying the lambda edge ARN and in the bucket policy role I am specifying the Cloudfront conical id and in the serverless framework or the cloud formation, it's not acceptable to use the output from another stack in a different region so that's my problem. I started a bounty cause the question is really important and blocking me so please if you have an answer for it let me know.

Comment: @JamesDean I updated the question to include the exact problem with code samples and images.

Comment: Can you push your code somewhere maybe in github in text format? It would be way easier for us to read your code.

Comment: @jellycsc I've posted those screenshots so I can highlight the lines but if you are interested to see the code I already posted it all in the answer for this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62492604/how-to-access-aws-cloudfront-that-connected-with-s3-bucket-via-bearer-token-of-a Also i updated the question

Comment: @Marzouk Please join the aws [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214788/aws-chat).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution was instead of moving everything over to `us-east-1`, just maintain two stacks which are the primary stack and the lambda edge stack. The primary stack resides in EU and the lambda edge stack resides in `us-east-1`. You can reference the lambda edge functions in `us-east-1` by using `${cf.us-east-1:another-stack.lambdaEdgeArn}`.

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible to reference Lambda@Edge deployed to `us-east-1` from other regions by `Fn:ImportValue`. In the CloudFormation template, there is a workaround by looking up the version-specific ARN dynamically and passing it as a template parameter for the CloudFront template, in a task file.

```
- name: Get Lambda Version-ARN
  shell:
    cmd: "
      aws lambda list-versions-by-function \
        --function-name '{{ lambda_func_name }}' \
        --region '{{ lambda_region }}' \
        --query \"max_by(Versions, &to_number(to_number(Version) || '0'))\" \
      | jq -r '.FunctionArn'
    "
  register: lambda_output

- set_fact:
    lambda_arn: "{{ lambda_output.stdout }}"

- name: CloudFront
  cloudformation:
    stack_name: "{{ stack_name }}"
    state: "{{ state }}"
    region: "{{ region }}"
    template: "roles/{{ role_name }}/templates/cloudfront-template.yml"
    template_parameters:
      LambdaARN: "{{ lambda_arn }}"
      ...
```